# How to soften the appearance of particles in Particular

Tags: after-effects

I'm doing a Particle system that looks like a Nebulae/BigBang subtle explosion, everything looks perfectly except for the 'grainy looking texture' of the particles.

If for example I add some quick Gaussian Blur, it looks better, but obviously, blurry.

Is there any way to make the 'particle texture' softer somehow and not that 'pixelated'? Like, no showing the 'little dots' but a true 'cloud mass' (not cloudet or striklet, these didn't work properly)

I'm using the basic sphere for particle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reckon try a lot more particles and make them much smaller. (But this will take much longer to process). You can feather the spheres too, which might give you the effect you need.